# Get Breadth First (Level) Order Without Constructing Red-Black Tree

Tags: algorithm, binary-search-tree, breadth-first-search

I have an ordered array of length `n` containing consecutive integer elements `1` to `n`. After constructing the red-black tree for this array, I can traverse this tree in level order using a standard breadth first search approach.

My question is, given any `n <= 100000000` (corresponding to an ordered array with consecutive integer elements from `1` to `n`), is it possible to bypass the construction of the tree and directly return the level order?

Comment: The possible red-back tree for that data is not unique: there are many such trees possible, and so the level order is not uniquely defined.

Comment: Maybe I needed to state this explicitly but I am only interested in the level order derived from constructing a balanced tree. So the first level would be the middle element of the array, the second level would be the middle element from the left half of the remaining array followed by the middle element from the right half, and so forth. In the case where we need find the middle for an array with an even number of elements then you’d choose the first element to the left of center.

Comment: Still it is possible to have different balanced trees for the same input, and so the levels would be different. For instance, if n=4, then level order can be any of these: [2][1,3][4] or [2][1,4][3] or [3][2,4][1] or [3][1,4][2]

Comment: Given the rule about even numbers, do you mean that you only consider the balanced tree where no subtree is left-heavy, i.e. for n=4 you would want [2][1,3][4]?

Comment: Yes, for `n=4`, I would expect the level order to produce `[2][1, 3][4]`, though, I would just want to return a flat array with `[2, 1, 3, 4]`. For `n=10`, I would expect the level order to be `[5][2, 8][1, 3, 6, 9],[4, 7, 10]` or `[5, 2, 8, 1, 3, 6, 9, 4, 7, 10]` when flattened

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind extra space, you can do this.

```
def level_order(n):
    queue = [(1, n)]
    i = 0
    while i < len(queue):
        a, b = queue[i]
        i += 1
        if a > b:
            continue
        m = (a + b) // 2
        yield m
        queue.append((a, m - 1))
        queue.append((m + 1, b))


print(list(level_order(13)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. While this works for small `n`, it seems to perform poorly (in both space and time) for `n = 100000000`.

Comment: @slaw it's asymptotically optimal in both space and time but not extra space. What are you actually trying to do?